# How to create custom URL http://mysite.com/username in Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am designing a small J2EE web application (for example, the service name would be like http://www.mysite.com). It uses Glassfish. Spec: When a user sign up into the web application, he will get a custom URL like

```
http://mysite.com/username
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.com?username=username&userId=xxxx
```

things i know is,this a part of is a part of directory-level configuration,and in Appache this can be done by configuring `.htaccess`.

How can i accomplish this in my web application. I am still developing the app. i have not hosted it yet.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PrettyFaces for URL rewriting in GlassFish: http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Comment: Tuckey UrlRewriteFilter seems to work pretty good too: http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you develop a web application when you install it in a servlet container (in your case glassfish) you define the application root that maps URL's to your web-app.

If you use /myapp as application root, the container will map requests to `http://mysite.com/myapp/*` to your web-app. Servlets in the web-app are mapped in the `web.xml` in which you map servlet class.

If you say, map the servlet `com.mysite.UserServlet` to `user` the container will map all URL's of the format `http://mysite.com/myapp/user*` to that servlet. You can use the `pathinfo` to retrieve the part after `/myapp/user` and parse it to extract the username in case you chose to use URL's like `http://mysite.com/myapp/user/Sam` instead of `http://mysite.com/myapp/user?name=Sam`

**Edit**

The method [HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) (quote) returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but precedes the query string. This method returns null if there was no extra path information.

So for `http://mysite.com/myapp/user/Sam` and a servlet mapped to `/user/` getPathInfo() would return `Sam`, which you can then use just like you would if you got the value as attribute.

For this, your `web.xml` would contain a mapping like:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>userservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mysite.UserServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>userservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: can u elaborate last para once more please.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like your login page should use POST instead of GET in the submit action.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Comment: I also don't see how this relates to the question.

Comment: @Stephen, do you agree with my analysis?  (aside from the link)

Comment: It is true that a login action should use a POST rather than a GET, but the OP is not talking about a login action.  He is talking about how to implement a fixed URL that denotes the user's personalized page.  If login is required, that would be (for example) triggered by visiting that URL.